# Should we use or avoid the chat feature, since future visitors may not encounter find the discussion in chat and may not benefit from it?

Tags: discussion, comments, chat

Stack Overflow offers chat to avoid long discussions in the comments.

Should we really use the chat feature or avoid it to help the users who might come late to the questions, say about 10 years later.

Comment: You're _welcome_ to use the chat feature, but if you're not interested in it then you can effectively treat it like it doesn't exist. A couple comments on a post won't cause any harm.

Comment: @Nick I supposed It's to avoid long discussions in comments. but it does not help other users on the site, and if the chats would be visible to all, then there will be no point for the chat feature to exist.

Comment: @Nick also, is there any feature that provides long discussions while being visible to the community with images, code snippets & more?

Comment: *"I supposed It's to avoid long discussions in a comments."* - What makes you say that? The FAQ says: *"discussion should more or less revolve around the same topics you'd find at Stack Overflow — but in an interactive, less strictly Q&A focused way. Do have fun ..."*. It makes no mention of it being for keeping discussion out of comments, that's just a common use, not "what it's for".

Comment: @Nick currently (2022) if we need to include an external source for say `an image` in the comment we need to add a URL to the source, which has a chance to disappear over time. what's the solution to this problem?

Comment: @AdisonMasih the "solution" is that comments are not permanent. Never meant to be.

Comment: For images you use i.stack.imgur.com, for actually external stuff you flag comments which are no longer useful as no longer needed.

Comment: @Nick thank you. that will surely help in improving the community.

Comment: What do you mean by *"...future visitors may not encounter find the discussion in chat"*? The comment referencing the chat being deleted? Or something else? What do future visitors miss out on (except the possibility that comments are deleted)? Can you elaborate?

Comment: "*avoid it to help the users who might come late to the questions, say about 10 years later.*" How does avoiding chat help future users?

Comment: This looks to be a non-issue. Nowhere do you provide real support for your proposal, not in your question, not in your comments.

Comment: Is the gist of the question that to see/access chat, it requires an account and a minimum number of reputation points (presuming that is the case)? And thus access to chat is restricted, in contrast to comments?

Comment: Let's be frank here; if you get to a point where something needs to be taken to chat, you're probably already beyond repair. The question is going to be not useful and either the author is lacking a lot of required understanding (and so you're in a loop of having to instruct and mentor them which is not the purpose of this site), or they're pigheadedly rejecting everything said to them and you're in an endless argument. Either way continuing in comments is going to be improper, taking it to chat is a better arena. Walking away is also perfectly fine though.

Comment: (I should have said "at a point of no return" instead of "beyond repair", that's kind of a weird thing to say I now realise after the fact)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Comments are meant to help future visitors only indirectly. They benefit future visitors because you help a post author improve/clarify a post, when possible (and even close/delete when not).

Then future visitors will encounter only the better version of the post, after it was improved in reaction to comments.

The use of chat to avoid long discussions in comments is to futher help future users by reducing the amount of distraction on page, so they can focus on the content that really matters: posts.

(Very often, if a question requires going to chat to be able to get it into an answerable state, you'd be further helping future visitors by flagging/voting to close the question).